# Magento2: change output template of field in system.xml

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, system.xml, file-upload

I have a file upload field in my `system.xml` file, declared in this way:

```
<field id="custom_file_upload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
    <label>Upload custom file</label>      
    <backend_model> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File </backend_model>
    <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1">home</upload_dir>
</field>
```

How do I change its HTML output?

Comment: what exactly do you want to change?

Comment: I'd like to change the way the uploaded file value is shown. Now it prints just the path where the file has been uploaded. I'd like to add a link to that file.